# Printing file size and time in C

Tags: c, file, printf, file-structure

I'm trying to print the file's size and time of the last access, last modification, and last change. But I get errors in the terminal. It says that the type of the returned value from buf.st_size is of type '__off_t' and the returned value from buf.st_atime, buf.st_mtime, & buf.st_ctime is of type '__time_t'.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  struct stat buf;

  if(argc==2){
    stat(argv[1],&buf);

    if(S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode))
      printf("It's a directoy.\n");

    else if(S_ISREG(buf.st_mode))
      printf("It's a file.\n");

    else
      printf("It's other.\n");

   printf("User ID: %d.\nGroup ID: %d.\n",buf.st_uid,buf.st_gid);

   printf("Size in bytes: %zd .\n",buf.st_size);

   printf("Last access: %s.\nLast modification: %s.\nLast change:        %d.\n",buf.st_atime,buf.st_mtime,buf.st_ctime);

   exit(0);
 }
 printf("No argument was given.\n");
}
```

Comment: Off-topic here, since a "debug my code" question (without any intuition of what could be wrong). BTW did you RTFM [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) carefully? Also compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`). Use also [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command

Comment: You're also not checking that the `stat()` call succeeded.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what do you mean by checking if the stat() call succeeded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time_t` is just an integer that represents the seconds after the epoch, 1 Jan 1970. On modern systems it is a 64-bit integer and depending on your system, you should be able to print it with `%lu` or `%llu`. You can also cast the parameter to match the format:

```
printf("Last access: %lu.\n", (long unsigned) buf.st_atime);
```

If you want a string representation, you can use [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). This function takes a format – use `"%c"` for the "preferred" format if you're lazy – a char buffer to fill and a `struct tm`, which contains the time and date broken into human-readable information.

To get the `struct tm` from the `time_t` timestamp, use [`localtime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3.html). Be sure to include `<time.h>` for these functions.

For example:

```
char str[32];

strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%c", localtime(&buf.st_atime));
printf("Last access: %s.\n", str);
```